# React NodeJS mySQL Can't login with password after Hashing

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, typescript, redux

I've created a salt and a hash function to hash my password.
I'm trying to login with the original password and it won't let me, but if I try to log in with the hashed password from the database it will give me to log in.

const salt = "HashedPasswordCheck";
hash function:

```
function has(plainText: string):string{
if(!plainText) return null;
const hashedText = crypto.createHmac("sha512", salt).update(plainText).digest("hex");
return hashedText; 
}
```

auth-logic.ts:

```
async function login(credentials:CredentialsModel):Promise<string>{
const error = credentials.validate();
if(error) throw new ValidationErrorModel(error);
const sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`;
const users = await dal.execute(sql, [credentials.username, credentials.password]);
credentials.password = cyber.hash(credentials.password);
if (users.length === 0) throw new UnauthorizedErrorModel("Incorrect username or 
password");
const user = users[0];
const token = cyber.getNewToken(user);
return token;
}
```

I tried to more the has before sending the query and still not working.
I checked this before and it was the same and worked but on this new project i'm working on it's not working properly.
credentials-model:

```
class CredentialsModel {
public username: string;
public password: string;
public constructor(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
  this.username = credentials.username;
  this.password = credentials.password;
}

public static validationSchema = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string().required().min(4).max(20),
  password: Joi.string().required().min(4).max(50)
});

public validate(): string {
  const result = CredentialsModel.validationSchema.validate(this);
  return result.error?.message;
}
}

export default CredentialsModel;
```

auth-controller.ts:

```
// http://localhost:3001/api/auth/login
router.post("/auth/login", async (request: Request, response: Response, next: 
NextFunction) => {
  try {
       const credentials = new CredentialsModel(request.body);
       const token = await authLogic.login(credentials);
       response.json(token);
}
catch(err:any){
   next(err);
}
});
```

I didn't add a React code because it's a back end problem..
Thank you for any one that can help!

Comment: Are you saving hash password in SQL database?

Comment: Yes, I'm saving it in the mySQL db.
This is what I'm asked to do.

Comment: So you have to first hash the password and after that call query to get user data from SQL database.

Comment: I tried to first hash then send the sql query.
Not helped.

Comment: Find user data by only username and compare that user's password with the body hash password manually in the function and use console.log to get an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: I've found my problem.
By accident I let the password save only up to 24 chars instead of the full hashed string.
Now it's working.

Comment: Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
I had 24 chars in my mySQL db, so it saved only part of the string and that's why I had an issue.
Solved by increasing the varchar amount on mySQL.